# I have this inconsistent matrix and I'm confused because it row reduced to echelon form.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following equation $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & \frac{1}{2}  \\ -2 & 2  \\ -2 & \frac{5}{2}  \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 4 \\5 \end{bmatrix}$

Then I put it in matrix form

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 2 \\ -2 & 2 & 4 \\ -2 & \frac{5}{2} & 5 \end{bmatrix}$$ which row reduces to
$$ = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0& 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

I'm confused what the row reduced form means. Does this mean x = 0, y = 0, z = 0? I don't have a z..

If I actually write out each equation, I get that theres no solution but how do I show that in matrix form?

Answer (score 2):

Once you have the RREF form of the augmented matrix, the way to read it is to reverse what you did to write the original augmented matrix. I.e., what system of equations has augmented matrix equal to the following?
$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$
It's the system given by:
$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}.$$
Multiplying this out, we have
$$\left\{ \begin{array}{l} 1\cdot x+0\cdot y = 0\\ 0 \cdot x + 1 \cdot y = 0 \\ 0 \cdot x + 0 \cdot y = 1\end{array}\right..$$
This is inconsistent because the third equation is never satisfied for any choice of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Ah, okay I'm dumb lol. I get it now.

Comment: You're not dumb! Also, as the other answer does, out it's good to place a vertical line before the last column of an augmented matrix to remind yourself that it is in fact an augmented matrix, so it is short hand for a system of equations.

Answer (score 1):

You should bear in mind that row reduction means different things in different contexts.

In this one, the matrix

$$A = \left(\left.\begin{matrix} 0 & \frac12 \\
-2 & 2 \\
-2 & \frac52
\end{matrix} \right|\begin{matrix}2\\4\\5\end{matrix}\right)$$

really is shorthand for the system of equations:
$$\begin{array}[rcl]{} \phantom-0\, x + \frac12\, y &=2\qquad&\text{(first row)}\\
\phantom-2 x \,-\,2\,y &=4\qquad&\text{(second row)}\\
-2 x +\frac52\,y &=5\qquad&\text{(third row)}\end{array}$$

Then, you can check that each of the elementary row reductions corresponds to either: adding a multiple of one equation to another, multiplying an equation by a non-zero constant or swapping the order of two equations. all of these will have the same solutions (if any).

In this way, row reduction takes your matrix representing your original system of equations and outputs a simpler matrix, which has the same solution set. As @kccu notes in their answer, the equations corresponding to the row reduced form have no answers!

Answer (score 1):

If you subtract the second row from the third row in $$A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 2 \\ -2 & 2 & 4 \\ -2 & \frac{5}{2} & 5 \end{bmatrix}$$

You get $$A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 2 \\ -2 & 2 & 4 \\ 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$
 The first row says $y=4$ and the third row says $y=2$  hence  the inconsistency.